# why isn't the appended row's data displayed after being submitted?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

this is my php code(1st page):

```
        <table width="600px" id="project">
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><textarea name="pro_1" cols="100" rows="2"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td><textarea name="pro_2" cols="100" rows="2"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td><textarea name="pro_3" cols="100" rows="2"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <input id="addbtn" type="button" name="addbtn" value="ADD">
```

incorporated with javascript for append the row when button is clicked:

```
$("#addbtn").click(function(){
    var num=parseInt($("#project tr:last").text());
        num+=1;
            $("#project").append("<tr><td>"+num+"</td><td><textarea name='pro_"+num+"' cols='100' rows='2'></textarea></td></tr>");
                });
```

The 2nd page is the important page where all data from 1st page display on it:

```
<table width="600px" id="project">
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><?php echo $_POST["pro_1"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td><?php echo $_POST["pro_2"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td><?php echo $_POST["pro_3"];?></td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

My problem is that the data of appended row didn't show on 2nd page.How to make it?

Comment: Although you're using PHP, the problem seems to be with javascript. Hence the retag.

Comment: do a `console.log(num);` or `alert(num);` in the click function to test its working okay and do a View Generated Source to see it created the html correctly

Comment: are you trying to find this:$("#project tr").last().children('td').first().text()?

Comment: @RayCheng find that one for what purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your secound page to something like this:

```
<table width="600px" id="project">
<?php
    $index = 1;
    while(isset($_POST["pro_".$index])) {
?>
       <tr>
           <td><?php echo $index; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $_POST["pro_".$index]; ?></td>
       </tr>
<?php 
    $index++;
} ?>
</table>
```

Comment: A better suggestion would be to use array notation for the input names.

Comment: That's true. Better to use `name="pro[]"` instead, but the solution is for code available

Comment: so did you mean is change it to `<textarea name="pro[2]" cols="100" rows="2">` on the 1st page?if so,how the php code like in 2nd page?

Comment: no just `name="pro[]"`, no need for index on first page, in this case the code on secound page will be like `
<table width="600px" id="project">
<?php
    $pro = $_POST["pro"];
    $index=0;
    foreach($pro as $p)) {
?>
       <tr>
           <td><?php echo $index++; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $p; ?></td>
       </tr>
<?php
} ?>
</table>`

Comment: Sorry for bad formatting I don't know how to format it in comments :(

Comment: no,i very appreciate your suggestion.A big thank to you

Comment: bro,I had try of your posted solution,but not work...

Comment: can you ost your tried code, please

Comment: same as what you posted solution.

Comment: the filled appended row didn't show anything and the static index start from 1 to 3,right?But the number appended it again 1 to 3,which mean 1,2,3,1,2,3.It will not automatically add up with the last row which is 3 and continue with 4 ,5 and so on once add button is clicked.

Comment: Try: `$("#project tr").last().children('td').first().text()` instead of `$("#project tr:last").text()` in your JS

Comment: I had try,is the samething

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29547/discussion-between-dharmesh-patel-and-jcchan)

Comment: halo,bro,did you hear me...